# Cython command to force explicit declaration of all variables

Tags: python, variables, cython

In Cython it is known that an undeclared variable type carries more overhead that slows down the whole process.

If this unknown variable type is used inside a nested loop like:

```
def test(b, c, m, n, p):
ctype double a
for i in range(m)
    for j in range(n)
        for k in range(p)
            a = b + c
return a
```

the overhead can be much higher. In a problem with many variables one can easily forget to declare one or another type, and the compiler will not raise a warning since Cython does the required overhead.

Is there a command in Cython to force all variables to be explicitly declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Cython it is known that an undeclared variable type carries more overhead that slows down the whole process.

You know wrong, there is [(limited) type inference](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=infer_types#compiler-directives), and [not every type annotation improves performance](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types) (e.g. unwrapping an int argument and then passing it to Python unchanged, wrapping it back up in a new object). A more useful metric is the amount of CPython API calls, which is what `cython -a` tells you.

Comment: maybe I was too general in the affirmation, [but in all the cases I've been working](https://github.com/saullocastro/desicos/blob/master/desicos/clpt.pyx), explicit declaration does improve the performance in orders of magnitude (this can be measured by undeclaring one variable inside the nested loops)

Comment: @SaulloCastro Good for you. In any case, the "typedness annotation" also uncovers other potential problems (e.g. the aforementioned int->object wrapping), so I'd recommend it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One should surely start with the solution proposed by the accepted answer.

Another great solution is to put the critical part of the code inside a `with nogil:` block. This will throw a compilation error if any Python API is called.

Usually the critical part is a deep for loop:

```
with nogil:
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(p):
                for l in range(q):
                    ...
```